# Open and Read file in C

Tags: c

I am trying to open a file in C, but I always get that it cannot open the file. I have the the following code:

```
        int i = 0;
        char delims[] = " ";
        char *result = NULL;
        char * results[10];
        result = strtok( cmdStr, delims );
        while( result != NULL ) {
            results[i] = result;
            i++;
            result = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }

        printf(results[1]); // it defo shows the name file here

        FILE *fp;
        char ch;

        if((fp = fopen(results[1],"r")) == NULL) {
            printf("Cannot open file.\n");
        } else {

        while((ch = fgetc( fp )) != EOF) {
            printf("%c", ch);
        }
        }
        fclose(fp);
```

Results[1] is the name of the file. So if I have something like "show file.txt" the results[0] will be show and results[1] the file.txt.

However it does not open it on the fopen. But if I insert in the code `fopen("file.txt", "r")`... it works.

Comment: Try using `char delims[] = " \n";`.

Comment: Unrelated: the second call to strtok() could also use delims. Unrelated: using a for() loop instead of a while() loop will make the code much cleare and save you three lines. Unrelated: `printf(results[1])` will do terrible things if results[1]  happens to contain a '%'. Unrelated. results[1] could also be NULL, or uninitialised.

Comment: You could verify that results[1] contains what you expect by using this debug statement instead: `printf("DEBUG:%s:DEBUG",results[1]);` Then your output should be `DEBUG:file.txt:DEBUG`. If it's anything else, that's your problem.

Comment: Trying printf("DEBUG:%s:DEBUG",results[1]); shows that it changes the line on second DEBUG. I've tried char delims[] = " \n"; without success.

Comment: if the file already exist make sure you have the right to read it.

Comment: Did you check the obvious things: file exists, file is in present working directory, file permissions allow opening?

Comment: Change your printf to printf("|%s|", results[1]) to see if there are any invisible characters around results[1]. If there is any padding between the file name and | or any parts of the string are on a newline, then you know the problem.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "changes the line on second DEBUG", or rather just edit your question to include the output.

Comment: As a general rule, always replace `printf("Cannot open file.\n");` with `perror( filename )`.  This provides 2 benefits: it prints a reason the open failed, and it puts it on the correct stream.  (Errors belong on `stderr`, not `stdout`.)

Comment: It solved adding \n on result = strtok(NULL, " \n");

Comment: In that case, you should mark cnicutar's answer as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that `results[1]` contains a stray newline at the end. As Daniel and Jerry suggest, a cheap fix would be to include `\n` in the delimiter array.

---

Unrelated: the type of `ch` should be `int` rather than `char`.

Comment: Seems like a fair guess. Easy fix: change `strtok(xxx, " ");` to `strtok(xxx, " \n");`